# Enforcing RBAC to React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

If we have a React component lets say `<App />` that is being rendered in another react component.
Can I have`<App doSomething/>` so that I can call the function doSomething before it is rendered?

Sorry, to add on the above question -  I want to declare `doSomething` outside in a library so that I can import and call it before the React component `<App doSomething/>` is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can read about lifecycle methods. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle

Time before `componentWillMount()` was what you are looking for. Now it is deprecated.

According to the diagram that was linked in the react docs page, the place to make that calls can be the `constructor`
http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/

Also you can set an default boolean to false, and in `componentDidMount` do what you want and set the boolean to true, but in the render method check if that boolean is true and render your things

Answer (score 0):

Yes

In this case `doSomething` is a prop that can be a function. Using React lifecycle methods you can call this function before the component renders.

From the react docs:

> getDerivedStateFromProps is invoked right before calling the render method, both on the initial mount and on subsequent updates. It should return an object to update the state, or null to update

(Since `ComponentWillMount` is deprecated).

EX:

```js
class App extends React.Component {

 static getDerivedStateFromProps(props) {
   props.sayHello();
    return null;
  }

  render() {
    console.log("Rendering");
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
 
}

class Hello extends React.Component {

  sayHello() {
    console.log("Hello!");
  }

  render() {
    return <App sayHello={this.sayHello} />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Edit:

It doesn't matter where the `doSomething` function comes from, you can pass it as a prop, or call it directly.